# Typecasting and inheritance in C++

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors

I have a problem. There are two classes:

```
struct Base {
    Base* retain() {
    //retain here
        return this;
    }
};

struct Derived : Base {
};


Derived *d1 = new Derived();
Derived *d2 = d1->retain(); //error here: need to typecast to Derived*
Derived *d3 = (Derived*)d1->retain(); //OK
```

Is there any way to rewrite retain() function in a way that I don't need to manually typecast result? In other words: retain() should return an object of the derived type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
template<typename T>
struct Base
{
    T* retain()
    {
        return (T*)this;
    }
};

struct Derived : Base<Derived>
{
};


Derived *d1 = new Derived();
Derived *d2 = d1->retain();
```

Alternatively:

```
struct Base
{
    template<typename T>
    void retain(T** ptr)
    {
        *ptr = (T*)this;
    }
};

struct Derived : Base
{
};

Derived *d1 = new Derived;
Derived *d2;
d1->retain(&d2);
```

Comment: This is better than my answer.  Prefer this one.

Comment: BTW, the first approach is called ["Curiously recurring template pattern" (CRTP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)

Answer (score 0):

Normally, when you do the kind of thing you are doing, the Base class will have a virtual destructor.  This allows run-time type identification.

You also probably want to write `struct Derived : public Base`, including the keyword `public`.

Explanation re the virtual destructor follows.

An object of a simple class, the class lacking virtual methods, is nothing but a collection of data in memory.  Code that has the address of such an object cannot tell, just by looking at the object, whether the object is of the base or the derived type.

*However,* if the base type has at least one virtual method, then the compiler adds a single, hidden pointer to each object of the type.  This pointer points to a table that, among other things, exactly identifies the object's type, thus making `dynamic_cast<>()` and other polymorphic operations possible on the pointer.

If all of this is new to you, then here is what I recommend trying next:  add a null virtual destructor `virtual ~Base() {}` to the Base class and then read about `dynamic_cast<>()`.  Next, you might wish to make the Base `retain()` virtual, too, and then to give Derived its own, overriding `retain()`.

Anyway, unless you can get more targeted advice, the foregoing should give you something with which to start.  Good luck.

Comment: the default inheritance access specifier for structures is public

Comment: I know what is virtual function and what is virtual destructor. Dynamic casting happens in runtime and I have a compile time error.